# Google Sheets Script - Checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this google app script to add a checkbox based on a watch column in google sheets.

However I need to add a checkbox in col1, col2 and col4?

Could someone please amend code below to do this, many thanks in advance.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const watchSheets = /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i;
  const watchColumn = 5;
  const checkboxColumn = 1;
  if (e.range.columnStart !== watchColumn
    || !e.source.getActiveSheet().getName().match(watchSheets)) {
    return;
  }
  const checkboxCell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, checkboxColumn);
  if (e.value) {
    checkboxCell.insertCheckboxes();
  } else {
    checkboxCell.clearDataValidations();
    checkboxCell.clearContent();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Change the `checkboxColumn` to an array with all the column indexes (`checkboxColumns`).
- Iterate through `checkboxColumns` (for example, using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) and, for each column, retrieve the corresponding cell and insert or clear the checkboxes (as in your current code).

#### Code snippet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const watchSheets = /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i;
  const watchColumn = 5;
  const checkboxColumns = [1, 2, 4];
  if (e.range.columnStart === watchColumn && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName().match(watchSheets)) {
    checkboxColumns.forEach(checkboxColumn => {
      const checkboxCell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, checkboxColumn);
      if (e.value) {
        checkboxCell.insertCheckboxes();
      } else {
        checkboxCell.clearDataValidations();
        checkboxCell.clearContent();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Many many thanks lamblichus! Works a treat!

Answer (score 2):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const watchSheets = /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i;
  const watchColumns = 5;

  // changes this to array so you can add multiple columns
  const checkboxColumns = [1, 2, 4]; 

  // fixed the first condition here
  if (checkboxColumns.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1
    || !e.source.getActiveSheet().getName().match(watchSheets)) {
    return;
  }
  
  // run through each watchColumns
  checkboxColumns.forEach( cellCol => {
    const checkboxCell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, cellCol);
    if (checkboxCell.getValue()) {
      checkboxCell.insertCheckboxes();
    } else {
      checkboxCell.clearDataValidations();
      checkboxCell.clearContent();
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi Neven, many thanks for your help. I tried running it bit get: Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 25 file: Code.gs

Comment: So what I'm trying to achieve is a checkbox to appear in col1, col2 and col4 when adjacent cell in col5 has been edited and not empty and then for the checkboxes to be removed when the cell in col5 is edited to empty.