# Google Sheets Script Modification - Insert checkboxes starting at row 4

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the checkbox script below which was kindly provided by another stackoverflow user.

However I'd like the script to start inserting the checkboxes and clearing from row 4 and down i.e. do not add checkboxes in rows 1-3 or clear in rows 1-3 if cell in col5 on rows 1-3 is edited.

Could someone please amend code to achieve this. Many thanks in advance.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const watchSheets = /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i;
  const watchColumn = 5;
  const checkboxColumns = [1, 2, 4];
  if (e.range.columnStart === watchColumn && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName().match(watchSheets)) {
    checkboxColumns.forEach(checkboxColumn => {
      const checkboxCell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, checkboxColumn);
      if (e.value) {
        checkboxCell.insertCheckboxes();
      } else {
        checkboxCell.clearDataValidations();
        checkboxCell.clearContent();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Working Code is:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const watchSheets = /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i;
  const watchColumn = 5;
  const checkboxColumns = [1, 2, 4];
  if (e.range.columnStart === watchColumn && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName().match(watchSheets) && e.range.rowStart >= 4) {
    checkboxColumns.forEach(checkboxColumn => {
      const checkboxCell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, checkboxColumn);
      if (e.value) {
        checkboxCell.insertCheckboxes();
      } else {
        checkboxCell.clearDataValidations();
        checkboxCell.clearContent();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean avoiding the checkboxes to be created if the edited row is above the 4th? If that's the case, Tanaike's answer should solve your issue. Or maybe you mean to insert multiple checkboxes, starting at row 4?

Comment: Hi lamblichus, thank you for responding, Tanaike's answer is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (e.value) {
  checkboxCell.insertCheckboxes();
```

#### To:

```
if (e.value && e.range.rowStart >= 4) {
  checkboxCell.insertCheckboxes();
```

- In this modification, when the edited row is more than row 4 including row 4, the script of `checkboxCell.insertCheckboxes()` is run.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. I tried your suggestion, it now doesn't add the checkboxes in rows 1-3, however if I edit col5 in row 3 it will clear the cells in col1, col2 & col4 in that row.

Comment: @Hibernian Please note that you didn't mention anything about clearing the checkboxes in your question. Also, the mention of `col1, col2 & col4` doesn't correspond to the code you provided; probably you should have provided [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69345665) instead.

Comment: @Hibernian In any case, checking `e.range.rowStart >= 4` in an outer `if` block should solve this.

Comment: @lamblichus, my bad, I put the wrong code in. I'll edit it now and put the code in that you made.

Comment: @lamblichus, I have put the correct code and clarified the requirements. I would be extremely grateful if you could edit the code above.

Comment: @Hibernian Just replace this: `if (e.range.columnStart === watchColumn && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName().match(watchSheets)) {` with this: `if (e.range.columnStart === watchColumn && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName().match(watchSheets) && e.range.rowStart >= 4) {`

Comment: @iamblichus Many thanks.